# Trying to get property 'fullname' of non-object (View: in laravel 7 when I want to show {{Auth::user()->fullname}} on dashboard.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am new comer in laravel, actually I want to show my logged user name on dashboard header user section but I have got the error but when I run `var_dump($usernm);` name showing but not showing on dashboard.blade.php please assist me.. Thanks

Trying to get property `fullname` of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\omemserp\resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)
this is my controller login code:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
        { 
           $validatedData = $request->validate([
           'userid' => 'required|max:255',
           'comp_code' => 'required',
           'password' => 'required|max:255',
            ]);

           if(Auth::attempt(['userid' => $request ->userid,'comp_code'=>$request ->comp_code,'password'=> $request ->password])){

               if(Auth::user()->role == 'ADMIN')
               {
               //.... This is the Auth user---
               $usernm = (Auth::user()->fullname);

               $comid = (Auth::user()->comp_code);

               $mcompany=Mcompany::where('ID', $comid)->first();

               session([

                   'comp_code' => $mcompany ->ID,
                   'COMPANYNAME' => $mcompany ->COMPANYNAME,
                   'FYF' => $mcompany ->FYF,
                   'FYE' => $mcompany ->FYE,
                   'ADDRESS' => $mcompany ->ADDRESS,
                   'WORKPHONE' => $mcompany ->WORKPHONE,
                   'MOBILE' => $mcompany ->MOBILE,
                   'EMAIL' => $mcompany ->EMAIL,
                   'PANNO' => $mcompany ->PANNO,
                   'c_gst_no' => $mcompany ->c_gst_no,
                   'STAX' => $mcompany ->STAX,

               ]);

               //return view('admin.dashboard');
               return redirect('admin-dashboard');
           }//nested if
           elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'USER') {

               return redirect('admin-userdashboard');
           }
           elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'ACCOUNTS') {

               return redirect('admin-useraccounts');
           }
            elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'MANAGEMENT') {

               return redirect('admin-usermanagement');
           }

           }
               Session::put('success', 'Ooops somthing wrong happens');
               return redirect()->route('custom-form');

       }
```

Comment: The issue is in your blade file, not your controller.

Comment: You are not passing data to view you are just redirecting? You need to return to view dashboard with user data passed.